# What does distance of a point from line being negative signify?

Tags: linear-algebra

When we take distance from the line, we take

$$ d = \frac{ Ax_o + By_o + C}{ \sqrt{A^2 +B^2}}$$

usually with a modulus on top, now my question is if I evaluate this distance as negative what does it mean? Can I decide on which half-plane a point using this?

Comment: Yes, compare with e.g. $(0,0)$ (use sign of $C$)

Comment: I think the negative sign signify nothing in particular (or probably the direction - no idea).

Comment: Usually, distances are positive, right ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding on the answer of @Andrew Chin, the sign says in which of the two half-planes (in which the line divides the whole plane) lays the point. If it is from the same side of the vector $(A,B)$ then the result is positive, otherwise negative. Sometime called *oriented distance*.

For example, for the line of equation $x-2y+1=0$ we have ${\bf n}=(A,B)=(1,-2)$ and the following graphic representation

[image]

Comment: How do I know what direction the vector is in?

Comment: @DDD4C4U see edit

Comment: Does multiplying equation of line by a negative one flip the orientation of normal vector?

Comment: @DDD4C4U yes, it does

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is based on the magnitude of a vector and is always positive, but the numerator is based on the scalar product.  Since the scalar product is based on the cosine ratio, if you find yourself a "negative distance", this just means that the angle between the vector being projected and the normal vector **you have decided to use** (i.e. $\vec n=(A,B)$ and not $\vec n=(-A, -B)$) is obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

What I learnt is that $$d =
\,\Large \mathbf{\pm} \normalsize\,
\frac{ Ax_o + By_o + C}{ \sqrt{A^2 +B^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers, if we have a function $$ f(x,y) = Ax+By +C$$ Then we can understand that the family of parallel lines of the form $ Ax+By + C' = 0$ is level sets to the above. Taking the gradient, we find the normal of the line as:

$$ \nabla F = <A,B>$$

This is what @enoztib was talking about