# Deriving the formula for distance between two parallel planes

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

Show that the distance between parallel planes, $ax + by + cz + d_1 = 0$,  and  $ax + by + cz + d_2 = 0$ is,

$$
D = \frac{|d_1-d_2|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}
$$

#### Solution:

(a) Get the distance from point (x, y, z) to the plane, $ax+by+cz+d_1 = 0$.

$$
 D = \frac{|ax+by+cz +d_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}
$$

(b) Get the value of ax + by + cz.

- $d_1 = d_2$ since $-d_1 = ax+by+cz$, and $-d_2 = ax+by+cz.$

(c) Substitute ax+by+cz into $-d_2$, since, $-d_2 = ax+by+cz$

$$
 D= \frac{|ax+by+cz +d_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} 
$$
$$
 D= \frac{|d_1 - d_2|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} 
$$

QED

Comment: I have edited the title so that the question may be helpful for a larger pool of people.

Comment: $ax_1 +by_1 +cy_1 = d_1 , \; ax_2 +by_2 +cy_2 = d_2\; \to \; a(x_2 -x_1)+ \cdots = d_2 -d_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $"d_1=d_2$ since$ −d_1=ax+by+cz$, and $−d_2=ax+by+cz."$

This is clearly wrong. Since the planes are parallel, by definition there is no $ (x,y,z)$ triplet which satisfies both conditions at once.

**Proof sketch:**

1. Draw the two parallel planes!  (let's call the two planes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$)
2. Pick one point on each plane, construct a vector from these two points [ assume coordinates of the point]
3. Dot this vector with the normal of the plane [ why? look at the picture!]

[image]

**Legend:**

- orange vector is the one connecting the point on each of the parallel planes
- Blue is the normal (same for both planes)

---

**The general solution:**

Assume two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$  then the vector connecting them is:

$$ \vec{r} = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1 , z_2 - z_1)$$

Now notice the equation in G Cab's comment:

$$ a(x_2 - x_1)  + b(y_2 - y_1) + c(z_2 - z_1) = d_2 - d_1$$

We can write this as:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_2 - x_1 \\ y_2 - y_1 \\ z_2 - z_1 \end{bmatrix} = d_2 - d_1$$

Now normalize the unit vector :

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2} } \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_2 - x_1 \\ y_2 - y_1 \\ z_2 - z_1 \end{bmatrix}= \frac{d_2 - d_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2} }$$

This quantity can be geometrically interpreted as the distance the perpendicular distance between two planes and hence:

$$ D= = \frac{d_2 - d_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2} }$$

You can take modulus on both sides but actually, the sign has meaning as is discussed in [this stack post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767405/what-does-distance-of-a-point-from-line-being-negative-signify)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I also feel it is wrong.

Comment: Do you wish for help on the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Yes, that would be a great help.

Comment: well, of course there is no triplet satisfying both equations : the planes are parallel. what we have to find is their **distance**

Comment: I have added a picture and written a proof sketch, I suggest you try it yourself. If you don't get it then don't hesitate to ask for hints

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try answering it myself.

Comment: The vector is <[(d2-d1)/a],0,0>, and normal is <a,b,c>, right? After that, I just have to get the scalar of the projection of the vector onto the normal vector right?

Comment: How did you conclude that the vector would be $ \frac{d_2 - d_1}{a} $? I suggest taking the most general choice of $ (x_1,  y_1 , z_1)$ and $ (x_2 , y_2 , z_2)$ as the point on each plane

Comment: And yep dot it onto the ** unit normal** and use the equations of plane to simplify the expression

Comment: I concluded that the vector would be, $\frac{d_1 - d_2}{a}$ rather by substituting y and z to 0 in both planes to get the value of x and uses these points, $(-\frac{d_2}{a},0,0)$ and $(-\frac{d_1}{a},0,0)$, as the initial and terminal points for the vector.

Comment: Actually, that should work. That should solve the problem, I had the idea in my head to do with most general points but even those two specific points will do :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've added a general solution, if this answer was helpful then you can accept it.